# How to create an average out of 3 Fivestar Fields?

Tags: rating

I want to create a Fivestar-Field which shows the average of 3 other ones.

Something like:

(Field A + Field B + Field C):3 = Field D

A,B and C are Fivestar-Fields which rate something and Field D is the average value out of the three.

I want the average to be showed via the star-widget of fivestar.

Is there a way to do that?

(I use Drupal 7)

Comment: So fields A, B, and C are voting fields (from the Fivestar module) on separate content types?

Comment: They are voting fields

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can able to do that using [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

You can read three field values rating using $node and set using below command

```
$node->field_name_of_your_fourth_field[$node->language][0]['rating'] = $average_value;
```